# What does it mean to describe the 'inter-relationships' of two things?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Given the essay question:

---

> "Between Canada and Nigeria describe and explain the
>   '**inter-relationships**' between and among Health and Economic
>   Development
>
> In your answer, focus on the similarities and differences of these
>   **inter-relationships**."

I don't understand what its asking

Comment: How do health and economic development influence and depend on each other. But seriously, how about looking words up in a dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

You are being asked to perform an interactive analysis for two different cases.  I would make the first case Canada.  I would consider a set of questions and prepare research to drill down to conclusions.  For example:

1. Does a healthy workforce yield high levels of employment?
2. Do healthy workers have high levels of productivity?
3. Does a healthy population free government resources to facilitate economic development?
4. Does strong economic development create a healthy environment?

Then analyze the Nigerian situation using the same criteria.

Does any of this make sense to you??